# SqlReader with multiple parameters

Tags: imageresizer

Is it possible to use the SqlReader plugin with multiple parameters for the primary key? Unfortunately, I'm using a third party database of images which has a primary key of two Int columns. I can't amend the table to add my own key field because the database is updated every night so the change would just be overwritten.

I thought of using a stored procedure which took a string and split and cast it into the two integer IDs, but the SP would also disappear every time the database was updated, as the update routine just deletes and recreates the database objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest forking [SqlReader (ImageResizer v4+!)](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/develop/Plugins/SqlReader/SqlReader.cs), renaming it,  and directly implementing the parsing changes you need.

There's no configuration to support your scenario, and the entire plugin is < 400loc. Take the direct approach.